# Create WebView in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

How can I implement a UIwebView for IOS in VisualStudio using Xamarin.IOS and C#?
I can create the webView in the Storyboard but how can I define the URL?

And how can I get the current Url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the webview after adding a webview in the storyboard, then the Properties will show at the right-bottom of VS like this:

[image]

Add the Name as the screenshot shows, press the Enter. Now you can load a URL for the WebView in your .cs file like this:

```
            NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString("https://www.google.com");
            NSUrlRequest urlRequest = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(url);
            webView.LoadRequest(urlRequest);
```

To get the current url of the webview when it already has loaded a URL via the code:

```
            webView.Request.Url.AbsoluteString;
```

Comment: There is an error:
The name 'webView' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'webView' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Have you add Name in the Properties? Do you add the code in the corresponding ViewController's .cs file? If there's a `UIKit.UIWebView webView { get; set; }` in the corresponding .designer.cs file?

Comment: When you add the control's Name in its Properties, the control is named and the name will be show in the corresponding .designer.cs file automatically. As the control's name is show in the .designer.cs file, it means you can set the control in the corresponding .cs file. If there's still any question, please let me know.

Comment: It didn't add the name of the UIWebView... now I tryed to add it again and there is an error: the parent view controller needs a codebehind. Do you know this error?

Comment: See [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19284/runtime-error-detected-parent-view-controller-needs-a-code-behind).

Comment: Can you check if you edited it in the right viewcontroller.cs which is set as the Class of the xib in storyboard?

Comment: BTW, You should not edit in the .designer.cs file, it is edited automatically.